# The Closed and $\partial \overline{\partial} -$ Closed Current

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ be a **Complex Manifold** of complex dimension $m$. Let $T$ be a Current on $M$.

What does **Directed Current** mean?

The current $T$ is said to be **Closed** if $dT=0$.

What does **The Current $T$ is $\partial \overline{\partial} -$ Closed** mean?

Comment: Typically $\partial \bar \partial$ is the composition of the operators $\partial$ and $\bar \partial$, so $\partial( \bar \partial T) = 0$. How do you apply $\partial$, $\bar \partial$ and $d$ to a current?

Comment: @red_trumpet Therefore, If the the current is closed then it is $\partial \overline{\partial} -$ closed. The converse is not necessarily true.

Comment: You should probably include some kind of source from which you are getting these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators $d, \partial, \overline \partial, \partial \overline \partial$ act on currents by duality, for instance $\langle dT, \alpha\rangle = \langle T, d \alpha \rangle$ (up to some sign) where $\alpha$ is a test form, and analogously for the other operators. Then, $\partial \overline \partial$- closed means that $\partial \overline \partial T = 0$.

A directed current is a current that is "tangent" to some foliation or lamination. There are different ways of defining them.

Positive closed directed currents are given locally by expressions of the form $\int [L_a] d \mu(\alpha)$, where $[L_a]$ is the current of integration along a plaque of the lamination/foliation directing the current and $\mu$ is a measure on a transverse section.

For positive $\partial \overline \partial$- closed directed currents what you get is something of the form $\int h_a [L_a] d \mu(\alpha)$ for some harmonic functions $h_a$.

A good reference is the recent survey

V. A. Nguyen - *Ergodic theorems for laminations and foliations: recent results and perspectives*. Acta Math. Vietnam., 46 (2021), no. 1, 9–101. [link.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs40306-020-00380-4)

Comment: Do you mean $\langle dT, \alpha \rangle = \langle T, d \alpha \rangle$?

Comment: @red_trumpet, of course. I fixed that. Thanks for noticing.